# Can I unlink ringtone and notification volume on Android 6?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, volume-control

I have installed [this volume control app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.hp.volume) on my Android 6.0 phone in order to tune notification volume independently from ringtone volume. However, when I tried to do that, I got the following dialog:

[image]

Could someone tell me where the above-mentioned setting is located? I have searched through the Sound&Notifications section, but didn't find anything.

Could it mean that the app doesn't support Android 6, or that it doesn't work without rooting?

Comment: There is no setting to do that in stock Android. when the app is installed it asks for permissions to modify volume state. Did you do that? I am actually surprised that this app claims to do that since AFAIK it requires root to do that

Comment: @beeshyams Yep, the app asked for permissions on startup (something volume- and call-related) which I granted.

Comment: I still think it is not possible without root

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it on Android, but there's an app called Volume Buttler that can do it without rooting your phone. https://www.guidingtech.com/separate-ringtone-notification-volume-android/

Comment: @Jakke I don't have that phone any more to test, but I remember having tried several such apps and none of them worked on Android 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having tried out several volume control apps without success, I think I can safely conclude that unlinking ringtone and notification volume controls is indeed impossible without rooting.